# How to start a new GUI with custom command from tty1?

Tags: x11, tty, mplayer, startx

I'd like to start a new GUI (say in `tty8`) from `tty1` with the command

```
mplayer -fs /tmp/movie.mp4
```

**How to start a new GUI with this custom command from tty1?**

The command

```
xinit  /usr/bin/mplayer -fs /usr/local/movie.mp4 $* -- :1
```

lead to a black screen instead of the movie.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mplayer` wants to read from standard input (you can use keyboard shortcuts in the terminal as well as in the mplayer window) and to display messages on standard output. When you run it directly from `xinit`, its standard input and standard output are connected to the same terminal that you ran `xinit` from. Since `mplayer` isn't the foreground process on that terminal, it can't access the terminal: it gets suspended with a [SIGTTOU](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Job-Control-Signals.html).

A workaround is to redirect standard input from `/dev/null`. (Redirecting stdout and stderr doesn't work, mplayer still gets suspended with SIGTTOU, I don't know why.)

```
xinit /bin/sh -c 'exec "$0" "$@" </dev/null" mplayer -fs /usr/local/movie.mp4 "$@" -- :1
```

Comment: Thanks. That is perfect. If no new GUI is needed:  `mplayer  -vo fbdev2 /dev/fb0 movie.mp4`