# Run GUI Application in a TTY Without Window Manager

Tags: tty, gui, elementary-os

What commands and variables need to be set up so I can run a GUI app on one the of the ttys without the Window Manager?

***Special Note: This question has been edited due to comments for testing and now includes the intended solution.***

My distro Elementary WM is started in tty7. I hope to start the **blender** app in another available tty.

So far I have these steps:

1. I open a terminal in Elementary OS.
2. I enter this command:

   su root -c 'Xorg :7 &'

This results in the screen going all black.

3. I press these keys to bring back the Window Manager:

   Ctrl + Alt + F7
4. I enter this code into the Terminal:

DISPLAY=:7 blender -p 0 0 1366 768

5. I test different tty's to find if Blender is in fact running on one of them by pressing:

   Ctrl + Alt + F1

   Ctrl + Alt + F2

`Ctrl + Alt + F3` ...

I find that Blender is in fact running on tty2

It is possible my question is not a duplicate [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/329374/how-to-start-a-new-gui-with-custom-command-from-tty1) because the question is slightly different and it's solution does not address my issue.

This is specific to my Linux Distro:

```
4.15.0-46-generic

NAME="elementary OS"
VERSION="5.0 Juno"
ID=elementary
ID_LIKE=ubuntu
PRETTY_NAME="elementary OS 5.0 Juno"
LOGO=distributor-logo
VERSION_ID="5.0"
HOME_URL="https://elementary.io/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://elementary.io/support"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://github.com/elementary/appcenter/issues/new"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://elementary.io/privacy-policy"
VERSION_CODENAME=juno
UBUNTU_CODENAME=bionic
```

*Why? The app I want to use has keyboard commands that conflict with the Window Manager commands, so I need to run the app without the Window Manager so that I can follow tutorials that use the standard settings vs. changing the keyboard shortcut settings and creating habits with non-standard keyboard shortcuts. (I tend to trust the app developers decisions on keyboard shortcuts and only customize after I've used the software for some time).*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to start a new GUI with custom command from tty1?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/329374/how-to-start-a-new-gui-with-custom-command-from-tty1)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94200/discussion-on-question-by-linux4life-run-gui-application-in-a-tty-without-window).